# How to solve the CA bundle included with OpenSSL may not be valid or up to date issue while trying to install a Puppet module?

Tags: puppet, openssl, certificate

Trying to fetch a module, I have the following output

```
Notice: Preparing to install into /usr/local/etc/puppet/modules ...
Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com ...
Error: Could not connect via HTTPS to https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com
  Unable to verify the SSL certificate
    The certificate may not be signed by a valid CA
    The CA bundle included with OpenSSL may not be valid or up to date
```

But my `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` is linked correctly, and the package `ca_root_nss-3.16.3` is up to date. Is there any information I can get from Puppet about how to proceed with diagnosing this? Maybe it's looking in the wrong location?

Comment: Are you sure your system clock and timezone is properly configured?

Comment: I don't think this is a Puppet issue - it might be with Ruby, though. Have you `strace` d your command to find out whether the up-to-date certificate file is actually read? Can you check that the current `GeoTrust SSL CA - G2` is in there?

Comment: Thank you both for the excellent advice: I checked `date` (which happened to be wildly off, but no dice); and I ran `ktrace`. In fact, `puppet` was attempting to read `/usr/local/openssl/cert.pem`, and upon symlinking my `cert.pem` there the error was fixed. This might be an issue with the port or something, which I'll pursue further. Thanks again.

Comment: Answer should be accepted instead of documenting in a question that this has been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I should be explicit about my solution. Following Felix Frank's advice to use `strace` (`ktrace` in FreeBSD), I performed

```
ktrace -d puppet module install puppetlabs/apache
```

the -d flag just being there in case child processes were involved.
Then, to recover the trace in a human readable format,

```
kdump | less
```

which revealed among other things the following bit

```
 84579 ruby19   CALL  open(0x804453968,0,0x1b6)
 84579 ruby19   NAMI  "/usr/local/openssl/cert.pem"
 84579 ruby19   RET   open -1 errno 2 No such file or directory
```

It isn't clear to me yet whether my system is just incorrectly configured, and that `cert.pem` was supposed to be there; or whether some other issue is at play. Either way, it fixed the immediate problem of not being able to install the module.

Comment: Good work. Glad that did some good. Still got a hunch that you will want to check your Ruby setup.